# How do you use an existing NSURLConnection with a different NSURLRequest?

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection

I'm using an NSURLConnection instance to login into a web site that requires authentication, returning a cookie.  Since the NSURLConnection stores the cookie, I would like to use the connection instance to logout.  Logging out just requires a URL different than the login URL, sending the cookie I got when logging in.  However, I can't see a way to assign a different NSURLRequest to an existing NSURLConnection -- at least with iOS 4.x.  I can't require iOS 5 yet.  I suppose I could record the cookie and create another NSURLConnection to logout.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You already gave the answer.

> I suppose I could record the cookie and create another NSURLConnection to logout. Any suggestions are appreciated.

NSURLConnection cannot be reused.